# How to set same luminance for several images?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, rgb, luminance

I have a lot of images with different luminance value. And i want to set luminance of image to standard value that is 0,196 or 49,98.

And what i want is:

- image that has overexposure the luminance should be decrease, and
- image that has under-exposure, the luminance should be increase.

[image: Standar image][image: Over-exposure]
[image: under-exposure]

Image 1 - standard image, Image 2 - Over-exposure, Image 3 - Under-exposure

The question is "how to set all of images has a exposure/luminance same like a standard image?"

Comment: There's no actual question here. Nothing to go on. It's nice to have wants and images though.

Comment: _"And i want to set luminance of image to standard value that is 0,196 or 49,98."_, 

I have absolutely no idea where those values come from. Do you have any reference for that?

Comment: The camera used this algorithm: calculate the mean luminosity of all (or central) pixels. Scale until you have 0.5 (white being 1.0, you may use 16bit int for calculation [factorR * R + factorG * G ...] as mean (so 18% grey). Now the camera are smarter and try to understand the picture (ignoring small highlights, finding if it is night or snow, and adjusting, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

So, I think there are two questions, you are asking.

**Q1:**

> And what i want is:
>
> - image that has overexposure the luminance should be decrease, and
> - image that has under-exposure, the luminance should be increase.

I believe what you are looking for is some sort of **histogram equalization**.

If you plot the histograms of those three images, they would look something like this:

[image: histograms]

As you can see,

- the distribution of the underexposed histogram is more concentrated in the lower bins, `roughly [0 ~ 55]`.
- the distribution of the overexposed histogram is more concentrated in the higher bins, `roughly [55 ~ 225]`.
- the distribution of *your* 'standard' histogram is more concentrated in the in-between bins, `roughly [15 ~ 145]`.

What you want to do is distribute the histograms more equally among all bins. You could try to come up with a little algorithm of your own or you could use the built-in MATLAB function `adapthisteq()` as explained [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/adapthisteq.html), on how to use. Playing with the different parameters, you could end up with a histogram distribution that produces the best image output for you. By default, the function `adapthisteq` would try to distribute the histogram over all 256 bins.

**Q2:**

> The question is "how to set all of images has a exposure/luminance same like a standard image?"

If you just want the histograms of the other two images to look like **your** 'standard' image, for that you could use the `imhistmatchn` function as explained [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imhistmatchn.html). to be honest, I have little experience with this function myself, but you could try it out.